# c++ XML file parsing problem

Tags: c++, xml

Can any one tell me how to change an xml file using c++ and xercesc code?

My file is on my desktop using  .

I know c++ file handling but don't know how to change attribute of xml file.

Can anybody tell me what I should do?

Any example, tutorial, book, etc., which can help me will be cordially accepted.

Comment: The documentation looks ok to me and it gives you a link to w3 that describes the other stuff you might not know. Have you examined xercesc page at all before asking this?

Comment: the question seems too general. Can you post some xml code and describe what needs to be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify an attribute using the [setAttribute function](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/apiDocs-2/classDOMElement.html#1a607d8c619c4aa4a59bc1a7bc5d4692) of [class DomElement](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/apiDocs-2/classDOMElement.html), as documentation says:

> If an attribute with that name is already present in the element, its value is changed to be that of the value parameter.